# How can I use Powershell to list the location, file name, and line of files containing a string?

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0

I have been bouncing around countless Stack posts trying to solve this but none have produced the result I want thus far.

Say I have a Directory as follows:

Main

- Sub 1

  - Sub 11
  - Sub 12

    - Sub 111
- Sub 2

Each sub folder contains files. I want to list out the following information for every instance of the string "dummy".

An example output would be:

**Main/Sub 1/Sub 11/Sub 111/testfile1.txt**

"I am the content of this file and I contain dummy!"

**Main/Sub 1/Sub 11/testfile2.txt**

"I am the content of this file and I contain dummy!"

**Main/Sub 2/testfile3.txt**

"I am the content of this file and I contain dummy!"

I have been able to get the list of the files so far but not the line itself using this one-liner:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object { $_ | Select-String -Pattern "dummy" } | ls -r  | Set-Content Output.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this, it's not the exact output you're looking for, this will return an object instead of strings which can be exported to CSV:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern "dummy" |
Select-Object FileName,Path,LineNumber,Line |
Export-Csv 'fullpath\to\Output.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Cool stuff, wasn't aware of this.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala neither did I, learnt this from mklement0 ;)

Comment: Wow this is great! Now I am on to the next step. Figuring out how to loop through each "Line" and search for the instance of that Line in another folder.

Comment: @user68288 good to know! post this as a new question with more details, we will try to help you :)

Comment: Ahhh, indeed. *Powershell Pops* (Mklement) is a living powershell dictionary! Always learning something new from him(: